# can not get timestamp value inserted in my database table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, timestamp

i have a column called "joined" in my database "users" table which i have created using migration

```
Schema::create('users',function(Blueprint $table){

             $table->increments('user_id');
             $table->string('username',100);
             $table->string('password',300);
             $table->string('full_name',100);
             $table->string('email',100);
             $table->timestamp('joined');
        });
```

But whenever i tried to insert a user in my table i get the following error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in
>   'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`username`, `password`,
>   `full_name`, `email`, `joined`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
>   (alzami, y$ckR7d.Pt05QRNZXXRGkoOuWDTZAxtDiQ0XA4O2UktSuBd244Oc3qe, al
>   zami rahman, alzami.shimanta@gmail.com, 20-03-16 10-37-11, 2016-03-20
>   10:37:11, 2016-03-20 10:37:11))

in my userController i have the following functionality to insert new user in my database

```
 $user=new User();
            $user->username=$request->username;
            $user->password=bcrypt($request->password);
            $user->full_name=$request->full_name;
            $user->email=$request->email;
            $user->joined=date('d-m-y H-i-s');
            $user->save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eloquent is trying to get access to timesptamps which do not exist. Try to declare `public $timestamps = false` in a `User` model.